# ssh bastion host proxy command

Tags: ssh

This is a weird situation where the same command works when inputted directly in shell but not when it's a ProxyCommand in ssh config file.

So this works:

```
 $ ssh -A -R 40022:git.some.pt:22 -t -t user@bastion.net ssh -t -t -R 40022:localhost:40022 user@destination.net
```

But this doesn't:

in ~/.ssh/config

```
Host destination
  ProxyCommand ssh -A -R 40022:git.some.pt:22 -t -t user@bastion.net ssh -t -t -R 40022:localhost:40022 user@destination.net

$ ssh destination
Bad packet length 218783296.
Disconnecting: Packet corrupt
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: The `ProxyCommand` needs to only contain the part that actually deals with the proxy, not the complete command.

Comment: Not sure what i should remove. Could you clarify on what exactly should go into the ProxyCommand? Thanks

Comment: Changed the `ProxyCommand` to `ProxyCommand ssh -A -R 40022:git.some.pt:22 -t -t someuser@bastionhost.net` but  got the same output `Bad packet length`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allow your command line `ssh` to connect to an ssh server somewhere. Your existing `ProxyCommand` doesn't do that - it provides all the means to log in somewhere and there's nothing left for your initial `ssh`.

This seems to work reasonably well for me, and I think I've got your chain right (obviously it's harder for me to test with the same hostnames that you use). Note that it does use `nc` rather than `ssh` on the bastion host, though:

```
Host destination.net
        User user
        ProxyCommand ssh -A user@bastion.net nc %h %p
        ForwardAgent yes
        RemoteForward 40022 git.some.pt:22
```

I have also been looking at running `/usr/sbin/sshd -i` on the end of `ssh -p %p user@%h` (instead of the `nc %h %p`), as suggested by [man ssh_config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config), but I cannot get that to work. Maybe you'll have more luck.

Comment: That works but I need the remote forwarding in both servers. I can only access git repo from my desktop so I have a remote forward to git.some.pt at 40022, and then I need to use this connection in the destination host so I need a new remote tunnel that uses this connection in the bastion host in the destination host. Hope that was clear! See my update above.

Comment: @Sofia, what I think I have set up is a tunnel from destination.net back through bastion to your desktop, where it's then re-routed to your git repo. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: You're right! I really thought both steps were needed so I didn't even try your option. Thanks :)

Comment: @Sofia the RemoteForward is overlaid on top of the connection established by the ProxyCommand, so it's "directly" from destination.net back to your PC